# Impulsive current and voltage sources

Tags: voltage

I am confused about the impulsive suppliers in RLC circuits. When are impulsive currents and voltages short circuit or open circuit happen in which time (like t=0 or t=infinity). Can anyone explain?

Comment: Welcome! There are several ways to combine R, L and C. Please draw a schematic of which one you are referring to. Have you tried to simulate your circuit?

Comment: No, i wil try to draw on ltspice thx